# Is every extension of ZFC interpretable in a finite extension of ZC + rank?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Let's speak of the theory $\sf ZC + rank$ as the first order set theory with axioms of Extensionality, Separation, infinity, and choice (written as usual), plus iterative powers and foundation, those are:

**Iterative Power:** $\forall \text { ordinal } \alpha \exists x : x=P^\alpha(\emptyset)$

where $P^\alpha(\emptyset) = \bigcup \{P(P^\beta(\emptyset)) : \beta < \alpha\} $

**Foundation:** $\forall x \exists \text { ordinal } \alpha: x \in P^\alpha (\emptyset)$

Now ordinal is meant to be a Von Neumann ordinal.

> is every extension of $\sf ZFC$ *interpretable* in a finite extension of $\sf ZC + rank$?
>
> is every finite extension of ZFC interpretable in a finite extension of ZC + rank?

Comment: Definitely not every extension - ZFC has uncountably many pairwise incompatible extensions (e.g. for any sequence $(a_n)\in\{1,2\}^\omega$ consider ZFC+"$2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+a_n}$" for all $n$), but ZC+rank has only countably many finite extensions, and each interprets only finitely many theories.

Comment: @Wojowu, then it might be more plausible to ask if every finite extension of ZFC is interpretable in a finite extension of ZC + rank?

Comment: @Wojowu, I just want to ask about the theories "ZFC + for all $n:2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+a_n}$" now each of these must be "effectively generated" so it must have a clear definition of its terms, it appears to me that $a$ is a sequence (so its domain is N) of binary strings which would code some reals I suppose. But this sequence must be *definable* otherwise the theory  "ZFC + for all $n:2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+a_n}$" is not well defined, and so not effectively generated. So we only have countably many such extensions.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, yes I assume consistency and that ZC+rank is $\Sigma_1$-sound.

Comment: @Wojowu, I see where I missed, I should have said any recursively axiomatizable extension of ZFC. I noticed that after reading Emil's answer, although my comment preceded this answer and it was clear that I was meaning effectively generated extensions of ZFC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\let\res\restriction\def\N{\mathbb N}$By the discussion in comments, it is missing from the question that all the theories are assumed **consistent** (otherwise the answer is trivially yes, as everything is interpretable in the inconsistent extension) and **recursively axiomatizable** (otherwise the answer is trivially no, as there are $2^\omega$ pairwise incompatible complete extensions of ZFC, while only countably many of these are interpretable in any given consistent extension of ZC + rank).

With these caveats, the answer to both questions is **yes**, for general reasons that work for most other pairs of natural theories. In what follows, if $T$ is a theory with a fixed r.e. set of axioms, let $\Box_T$ denote the formalized provability predicate for $T$, and $T\res n$ the theory axiomatized by the axioms of $T$ with Gödel number below $n$.

> **Proposition.** Let $S$ be an extension of $I\Delta_0+\mathrm{EXP}$, and $T$ be a recursively axiomatized theory such that
>   $$\tag{$*$}S\vdash\Box_{T\res n}\phi\implies T\vdash\phi$$
>   for all $n\in\N$ and all $T$-sentences $\phi$. Then every consistent r.e. extension of $T$ is interpretable in a consistent finite extension of $S$.

Observe that $(*)$ holds whenever $S\subseteq T$ (or just $S$ is $\Sigma_1$-conservative over $T$) and $T$ is a locally essentially reflexive theory, for example $S=\mathrm{ZC+rank}$ and $T=\mathrm{ZFC}$. But in fact, $(*)$ holds whenever $S$ is $\Sigma_1$-sound, which pretty much any natural theory is. Also, it is not difficult to show that if $S$ is locally essentially reflexive, then condition $(*)$ is *necessary*.

**Proof.** Let $U\supseteq T$ be recursively axiomatized and consistent. Then $(*)$ implies that
$$V=S+\{\mathrm{Con}_{U\res n}:n\in\N\}\equiv S+\{\neg\Box_{T\res n}\neg\phi:n\in\N,\phi\in U\}$$
is consistent; since it is an extension of $S$ by a r.e. set of $\Pi_1$-sentences, there exists a $\Pi_1$-sentence $\psi$ such that $S+\psi$ is a $\Sigma_1$-conservative extension of $V$ by a theorem of Lindström [1]. In particular, $S+\psi$ is consistent, and since it proves $\mathrm{Con}_{U\res n}$ for all $n\in\N$, it interprets $U$ by the usual interpretation existence lemma. QED

**Reference:**

[1] Per Lindström: *On partially conservative sentences and interpretability*, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 91 (1984), no. 3, pp. 436–443, doi: [10.2307/2045318](https://doi.org/10.2307/2045318).